# WordPress Page URL rewrite Issue

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite wordpress URL.

Currently My URL is : http://www.example.com/about/?pagekey=team1
and I need like ; http://www.example.com/about/team1

Here About is one page template and I've setup for wordpress custom parameter so, when you pass pagekey to this page it will take key and based on that display result.

Now, I need to show user friendly, can anybody have idea how to do this.

currently my parmalink is set to "PostName".

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you create child pages from this About page? Then in the theme you could retrieve the URL and do whatever you need (the same as the parameter you're using now).
Creating child pages feels like an easier solution to manage your content (even for non-tech savvy users).

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the WordPress codex here and create 2 files:

page-about.php
single-about.php (this one will be for the teams)

you should create CPT (custom post type) with all the custom post type fields you need for this eg.

Name,
Title,
Position,
Image,
Tag,
Taxonomy,
.... etc

then you will pass the custom post type query (the query) before the loop and you will be able to access the single-about.php from page-about.php

that'all.

Cheers and hope this helps